# android listviews matching layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I created a layout.
I putted a 2 `relative_layouts` on top of each other. 
I can slide the top layout to the left. Depending on the slide, the bottom `layout`changes color.

I want to use this layout in 2 different `listviews`. 
I want to change the layout of the top layout in the 2 listviews.
Can i put the layout in some kind of interface?

I hope this helps
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, please try to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Better to put imageview instead of layout

Comment: i can't, because i need to change all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution.
I Used a viewstub. It solved my problem